# What is the Potential difference in $C_1$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]

I can not seem to figure this out. My try so far:

- put C2 and C4 as C' by parallel
- put C' and C1 as C'' by series
- Finally, Put C'' and C3 and C5 as Ct by series
- find Qt by Qt=Ct*V

after finding the total Charge, i tried calculating backward toward V1 but could not manage to get the right answer. I found V1=99V which is wrong. P.S. The correct answer is 0.

Also i couldn't understand how a capacitor with 0 potential difference like.

Comment: Actually it's wheatstone bridge.Thus no current will flow through C1.You can just remove c1 and solve question without it

Comment: It has to be zero by symmetry since the capacitances on the top are the same as those on the bottom.